# .NET MVC showing a variable value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the this set up and am trying to get lkup_1_txt to show in the page as either text or the selected item in the dropdown.
I have tried the following

```
@lkup1
```

and

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lkup1)
```

and

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lkup1)}
```

This is my structure - 
 Model for Look Up Reference drop down selection

```
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModelForDropDown
    {
        public string SelectedItemText { get; set; }
        public List<ListItem> ItemListText { get; set; }
    }

    public class LkupResultRecord
    {
        public ModelForDropDown lkup_1_txt { get; set; }
        public ModelForDropDown lkup_2_txt { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller for the create new lkup1txt dropdown  -

```
    public ActionResult LkupRef_Lkup1()
    { 
        return View(lkuprefdao.getValuesForLkupTxtDropDown());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LkupRef_Lkup1(string lkup_1_txt)
    { return RedirectToAction("LkupRef_Lkup2", "LkupRef", new
        {
            lkup_1_txt = lkup_1_txt
        });
    }
```

Controller for the create new lkup2txt dropdown -

```
    public ActionResult LkupRef_Lkup2()
    { 
        if (lkuprefdao.IsDataRefreshDowntime() == true) { return RedirectToAction("BadgerWeb_RestrictedAccess", "LkupRef"); }
        return View(lkuprefdao.getValuesForLkupTxtDropDown());
    }
```

and the view where I want the lkup_1_txt to display -

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>lkup_1_txt</td>
        <td>  @Html.DisplayFor(lkup_1_txt) </td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
       <td> lkup_2_txt </td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("lkup_2_txt", new SelectList(Model.lkup_2_txt.ItemListText, "Value", "Text"), null, new { style = "width: 650px;" })</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 }
```

I

Comment: So far it looks like a rather extreme example of programming by trial and error. Do you have a `lkup1` segment defined in your route? Do you have a `lkup1` property in the class you are passing as the model, and if so, what is the code that takes the value from the URL and assigns to this property in the controller?

Comment: How are you "passing the variable"?

Comment: Yes - this is trial and error.  I am a coldfusion user who got thrown this and I am desperately trying to understand it. Yes, I have lkup1 in the model. I pass the variable in the controller -  

return RedirectToAction("Lkup2", "LkupRef", new
            {
                lkup1 = lkup1
            });

Comment: And that `Lkup2` action has a parameter `string lkup1`, and you copy its value into the model you then pass to the view?

Comment: Show us fully how you create and populate the model

Comment: Have you take the introductory ASP.NET MVC tutorial provided by Microsoft? You can find it for free online. It might help you get your head around the concepts a bit better.

Comment: P.S. I added an answer below based on what I think you are trying to do and what I think you need to do to solve it. There isn't quite enough info in your question for me to be 100% certain this is the right approach but I think it ought to work.

Comment: Thank you!  I will get started on that course tonight but this really helps in the meantime.  I was thrown this and have to get it working this week so I tried to dive right in.

Comment: No problem. If my answer helps you solve the problem please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click on the tick mark next to it so it turns green) - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's all still a bit unclear and doesn't make a great deal of sense, but I think you probably want something like this:

1) define `lkup_1_txt` as a string in your model, to match with the querystring value you're trying to feed to it. Defining it as a complex type like `ModelForDropDown` (as you did) doesn't appear to make any sense.

```
public class LkupResultRecord
{
    public string lkup_1_txt { get; set; }
    public ModelForDropDown lkup_2_txt { get; set; }
}
```

2) Add a parameter to allow the `LkupRef_Lkup2()` action method to receive the input value from the redirect (or from a direct request). Right now it is just ignoring the input. And also modify the action method code so you can add the incoming lookup text to the model before passing it to the view.

```
public ActionResult LkupRef_Lkup2(string lkup_1_txt)
{ 
    if (lkuprefdao.IsDataRefreshDowntime() == true) { return RedirectToAction("BadgerWeb_RestrictedAccess", "LkupRef"); }
    LkupResultRecord model = lkuprefdao.getValuesForLkupTxtDropDown();
    model.lkup_1_txt = lkup_1_txt; //add the lookup text to the model
    return View(model);
}
```

3) Modify the view so it can read the lookup text from the model property:

```
<td>lkup_1_txt</td>
<td>  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.lkup_1_txt) </td>
```